# react native getting network error when sending files with axios

Tags: react-native, file-upload, axios, api-platform.com

i'm using api platform to create end Point to handle images upload.
My api require a file type to make a post request.
This is an example of post request using post man :

[image]

I want to handle sending images with axios using react native.

I created a post request like this :

```
 this.setState({
      avatarSource: source,
    });

    console.log(this.state.avatarSource.uri);
    const data = new FormData();

    data.append('file', {
      uri: this.state.avatarSource.uri,
      // show full image path in my device
      //  file:///storage/emulated/0/Pictures/image-c40b64fc-6d74-46a7-9016-191aff3740dd.jpg
    });

    axios
      .post(`${API.URL}/media_objects`, data, {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
      })
      .then((resp) => console.log(resp))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err.message));
  }
});
```

I'm sending the full path of image in my phone to the api but i got "Network Error"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by commenting this line in ReactNativeFlipper.java :

```
  NetworkFlipperPlugin networkFlipperPlugin = new NetworkFlipperPlugin();
  NetworkingModule.setCustomClientBuilder(
      new NetworkingModule.CustomClientBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void apply(OkHttpClient.Builder builder) {
          // builder.addNetworkInterceptor(new FlipperOkhttpInterceptor(networkFlipperPlugin)); // add comment here and build android 
        }
      });
  client.addPlugin(networkFlipperPlugin);
  client.start();
```